# How can I duplicate LAMP install stack on another Centos 6.4 with minimal commands

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, lamp

I have just made new amazon ec2 instance and i want to install LAMP stack with all plugins or modules required.

I already have local host where i have everything installed.

Is there any way that i get whats all modules /packages are installed on current centos 6.4 so that with just less commands i get everything on EC2 rather than getting error and then installing that partucular thing.

Something like whats currently installed in Localsystem , i export that as command and then execute that on Ec2

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I already have what i need in existing centos installation . Any command to export that. or i want everything for 90% webhosting companies provide for php apache

Answer (score 0):

you might try starting with having the same packages on the system like is advised on
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71/duplicating-a-linux-installation-yum-based

If they are the same distro, then on the old server

```
rpm -qa > installed-software.log
```

or if you don't care what exact version of the package it is you can use

```
rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}\n" > installed-software.log
```

transfer the log file to the new server and run the command

```
yum -y install $(cat /home/user/installed-software.log)
```

As for any non yum based addons the answer is, it depends.